# Alert to popup once a day swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I am looking to have an alert popup once a day as a UIAlert for users to direct them to a website for general support. As I have yet to dive into anything like this yet in programming or swift language I was wondering how would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: Basic question. Divide your problem into smaller one and find a solution over the internet. Voting for closing

Comment: Everything I find on anything similar is notification based and not based on doing this with alerts....

Comment: In general, you are not likely to find the exact solution to your problem, you should do like @JulianKróls suggested, divide your problem into smaller problems (Show an alert, execute a function once per day) and find the solution for them. If you still can't find the solution for that specific, smaller problem, then you should ask a question. If you don't put any effort into the problem, we are unlikely to help you.

Comment: I wouldn't ask the question here if I hadn't exhausted searching the web myself. If in the future you are saying I should then I will. But I know how to show an alert...the problem is coming from execution of the function once a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

1. On first app open, show the alert.
2. Save the current date in NSUserDefaults so you know when the alert was last shown.
3. The next time the app is opened, compare the current date, with the date saved in NSUserDefaults. If it has been more than 24 hours, show the alert and save the current date.